# How to use Firebase code in Services in android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing this app in Android which lets me get the newsupdates that I have stored in firebase database. Now I want the notifications as my database is updated. For this I am trying to use Services so that I can run Firebase addValueEventListener in the handleMessage section of Services, but my app crashes whenever it encounters the firebase code. Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix it?

Here's my code....

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    try {
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(firebase_url);
            final Firebase ref_2013 = new Firebase(firebase_url + "Btech 2013" + "/posts");
            final Firebase ref_2014 = new Firebase(firebase_url + "Btech 2014" + "/posts");
            final Firebase ref_2015 = new Firebase(firebase_url + "Btech 2015" + "/posts");
            final Firebase ref_2016 = new Firebase(firebase_url + "Btech 2016" + "/posts");
   }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(NotificationService.this,"firebase and noti thrown",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 }
```

**My Service works fine if I do some normal work like generating toasts but as I use firebase code it crashes**

Comment: Can you share the Exception

Comment: Whats the crash  ??? please add your log with your answer

Comment: Thanks that you asked me to share the exception. I found out that I wasn't using Firebase.setAndroidContext().

It was working fine everywhere (without using it) except in the service class so I didn't realize it earlier

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I wasn't using Firebase.setAndroidContext(). It was working fine everywhere (without using setAndroidContext() ) except in the service class so I didn't realize it earlier.

**So we must use Firebase.setAndroidContext() in onCreate() or onhandleMessage() (for  Service class) before using any reference to Firebase otherwise it could crash at some places like here in Services**